# Rails: query parameter vs post parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose you have a url

```
localhost:3000?a=1
```

and in the request, you also have a post parameter

```
a=2
```

What would

`params[:a]` be in this case? **does it depend on the HTTP verb?**

If it does depend on the HTTP verb,

what if your form looks like

```
<form method='post' action='/?a=2'>
  <input type='hidden' name='a' value='3'/>
</form>
```

what would `params[:a]` be in this case?

**UPDATE**

So I just did a small experiment and used Chrome Debugger to append `?authenticity_token=abc` the action url. I looked at the server log and I saw that parameters has `authenticity_token => 'abc'`. I also believe that the method is `POST` in this case.

Let me know what you guys came up with.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When I tried this in a sample code, what I was able to see was that query parameters(GET) are given precedence than the POST body. So, I went digging into the code of `Rack` which handles the HTTP requests in Rails. Here is the code from [request.rb](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb)

```
# Returns the data recieved in the query string.
def GET
  ....
end

# Returns the data recieved in the request body.
#
# This method support both application/x-www-form-urlencoded and
# multipart/form-data.
def POST
  ....
end

# The union of GET and POST data.
def params
  @params ||= self.GET.merge(self.POST)
rescue EOFError
  self.GET
end
```

Here, the method

- GET - returns the query parameters in a hash format
- POST - returns the post body in a hash format

So, according to the code for `params`, the GET parameters should get overridden by POST parameters in case of identical keys. (`self.GET.merge(self.POST)`). But, this is contrary to what I got when I tried it practically.

So, the only chance is that this code is being overridden by Rails. When I thought about it, it made perfect sense as the `params` hash from the Rails will always contain `"controller"` and `"action"` keys, which will be absent in case of Rack. So, I looked at the code of Rails also, and found that `params` method was indeed being overridden. Take a look at [request.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb) and [parameters.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb) in Rails source code. In [parameters.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb), we have:

```
  # Returns both GET and POST \parameters in a single hash.
  def parameters
    @env["action_dispatch.request.parameters"] ||= begin
      params = request_parameters.merge(query_parameters)
      params.merge!(path_parameters)
      encode_params(params).with_indifferent_access
    end
  end
  alias :params :parameters
```

and in [request.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb):

```
# Override Rack's GET method to support indifferent access
def GET
  @env["action_dispatch.request.query_parameters"] ||= (normalize_parameters(super) || {})
end
alias :query_parameters :GET

# Override Rack's POST method to support indifferent access
def POST
  @env["action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"] ||= (normalize_parameters(super) || {})
end
alias :request_parameters :POST
```

So, here

- query_parameters - Alias for the GET method
- request_parameters - Alias for the POST method
- path_parameters - Method which returns the controller and action for the request as a hash
- parameters - Alias for `params` (It was overridden here)

Note that GET method and POST method were also overridden, mainly to convert the hash returned to an object of HashWithIndifferentAccess.

So, looking at the code here (`params = request_parameters.merge(query_parameters)`),  it becomes evident that POST parameters are overridden by GET parameters in case of identical keys, in Rails. Or in other words, GET parameters are given precedence over POST parameters.

Comment: Added note that you can get access to the `ActionDispatch::Request` object in the controller method: `request.query_parameters` and `request.request_parameters` from any controller method will get you the different params by type.

Comment: @keaplogik that is definitely worth noting.

Answer (score 8):

Rails [uses](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) `Rack::Request` for HTTP requests.  However, it redefines the `Rack` [`params`](https://raw.github.com/rack/rack/master/lib/rack/request.rb) method in `ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters` (via an alias).

This [`params`](https://raw.github.com/rails/rails/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb) method, which returns request parameters, is implemented as:

```
  # Returns both GET and POST \parameters in a single hash.
  def parameters
    @env["action_dispatch.request.parameters"] ||= begin
      params = request_parameters.merge(query_parameters)
      params.merge!(path_parameters)
      encode_params(params).with_indifferent_access
    end
  end
  alias :params :parameters
```

Note the aliased `parameters` method.

Unless redefined, parameters from the query string will overwrite parameters from the POST body.

Comment: then can you explain why my experiment gave me that result? It's under **Update**

Comment: I missed a critical piece of code.  ActionDispatch::Request includes ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters, which redefines params.  Updating my answer.

Comment: @toddsundsted..+1..you beat me in the update of the answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be 2.  But for routing, it would match against the '1'.

If you want, you can use request.GET and request.POST to access the get and post vars.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't depend on de HTTP verb but you sure can have different actions to handle `GET` and `POST` or it can be the same and you'll get `params[:a] in both cases.

Comment: I might have written my question poorly but my questions is that what if there are post param and query param with the same key and it is requested through a POST method. Which would take precedence over which?

Comment: Just made a test and the input value gets ignored, then the one in the `form` tag gets priority.