# Rails parameters going missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, parameters

I'm having a bit of trouble with Rails parameters being filtered or not being parsed. It works fine when it's running locally on WEBRick but once it's up on Heroku it ignores a bunch of submitted form parameters (they aren't added to params[]).

I submit the form and it falls over because it's expecting a value that isn't there. Airbrake tells me that **rack.request.form_hash** is this:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"8CZUmWc7qB1mWAbyn9NeGmygRVczdZCtI3CXwu0DUV4=", **"survey_entry"=>{"pupil"=>{"id"=>"2784", "non_vrh"=>"f", "initials"=>"A", "surname"=>"ABC", "year_group_id"=>"5", "age_this_september_years"=>"", "age_this_september_months"=>"", "current_reading_level"=>""}, "questionnaire"=>{"answer"=>{"21"=>"6", "22"=>"2", "39"=>"", "40"=>""}}}}**

But it also tells me that **action_dispatch.request.parameters** is this:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"8CZUmWc7qB1mWAbyn9NeGmygRVczdZCtI3CXwu0DUV4=", **"survey_entry"=>""**, "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"survey_entries", "id"=>"7"}

So it's doubtless something noobish and foolish that I'm doing but it's got me flummoxed at the moment :/

---

**UPDATE**

Curiously, a form submitted from the same page (but with slightly different fields) works fine:

utf8:✓

_method:put

authenticity_token:HLCXURx1BosuXlVYwBuOP+DxJwdY3SKwilx1CJDuwT8=

survey_entry[pupil][id]:2485

survey_entry[pupil][non_vrh]:f

survey_entry[pupil][initials]:AAS

survey_entry[pupil][surname]:ABC

survey_entry[pupil][year_group_id]:4

survey_entry[pupil][attendance_pct]:

survey_entry[pupil][reading_level][at_placement]:12

survey_entry[pupil][reading_level][at_term1]:

survey_entry[pupil][reading_level][at_term2]:

survey_entry[pupil][reading_level][at_term3]:

survey_entry[pupil][previous_progress]:

survey_entry[pupil][target_rl_id]:

survey_entry[pupil][english_first_language]:0

survey_entry[pupil][english_first_language]:1

survey_entry[pupil][care_order]:0

survey_entry[pupil][lac_funded]:0

survey_entry[pupil][free_meals]:0

survey_entry[pupil][selection_reason_id]:4

survey_entry[pupil][other_selection_reason]:

survey_entry[questionnaire][answer[3]]:2

survey_entry[questionnaire][answer[4]]:2

survey_entry[questionnaire][answer[13]]:3

survey_entry[questionnaire][answer[14]]:3

survey_entry[questionnaire][answer[20]]:3

Comment: By any chance do you have filters set anywhere in your app via: `env["action_dispatch.parameter_filter"]`?

Comment: That's a good question, I didn't know about that. But sadly no, a global search on 'parameter_filter' comes up empty

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. I have a very similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, suffice to say that I was being really stupid. I'll blame it on being a bit under the weather. Thanks to Steve for trying to help, I shall now crawl off in shame :)

Comment: Who were you, Jerome? _What did you see?!_ https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: ... Did you have two copies of the same field on the page as well...?

Comment: Hahaha :) It was quite a while ago and it's been some time since I touched Rails so my memory largely fails me but I think I was doing something awful, like I was actually monkeying around with params[] somewhere. 

Glad you got to the bottom of your particular scenario of nightmarish frustration!

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing survey_entry as a URL parameter by any chance?

This [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510235/rails-query-parameter-vs-post-parameter) points to an issue of query parameters verses post parameters that would explain your current behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the response Steve, that sounded very promising. Unfortunately nothing on the querystring :(

Comment: what does 'heroku logs -t --app your-app-name' show? 

You might want to update you question with the form code fragment.